# Redirect or Rewrite partial query string

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am getting a partial query string, at least that's what I think its called, and would like to either **Redirect** to 404.php or **Rewrite** to correct form.

Getting **/?prod=** instead of the correct form of **/proddetail.php?prod=**

Anyone got any thoughts?

Comment: You should post what you have tried

Comment: I haven't a clue what to do. Hence the question.

Comment: I think you've forgotten to add your code...

Comment: Perhaps I did make myself clear. In looking through the web logs I see that I am getting /?prod= and these are being reported as 200 whereas they should be 404. The correct form is /proddetail.php?prod=

Comment: A screenshot is more helpful..

Answer (score 1):

With `.htaccess` you can redirect as follows

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^prod=$
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ /proddetail.php [R=302,L]
```

This will keep the original query string

OR with php you can use:

```
if (isset($_GET['prod'])) {
    // do something eg redirect
}
```